# Resizing an drawabletop image fixed to textview

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a TextView with a drawabletop image, but the image is big and I need to resize it:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/football_pitch">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playerNameTop"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="358dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_football_top"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to resize it via the design view, but it just crops the image when I reduce the size.
How do I go about resizing the image itself, without cropping the image?

I think if I make the image smaller, I will have to increase the text size, which I can do just fine.
So now I need to scale down the image but for some reason it also cuts off the side of the image:

[This image shows me resizing it via the design view. As you can see it has cropped the bottom out so you cannot see the text[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di5mM.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always avoid to use `drawableTop` and other similars. Do it in more customizable way:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/your_drawable"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playerNameTop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I should have added, that I am going to recreate the image many times and then add custom text at the bottom. So with Linear layout, can I recreate the layout as many times as I need to. Lets say in recycler view, I can create Llayout instead?

Comment: Ofcourse, it will be more customizable way than drawableTop, because you can change everything of your image and text separately without impact on each other.

Comment: Ok, will give this ago and update once I have done it. Thanks!